# Is there a way to name the fields when receiving a ValueTuple as a parameter?

Tags: c#, valuetuple

There is a method that receives a `ValueTuple` and returns it after modifying it. In this case, can I specify the field name of the `ValueTuple` in the method parameter?

```
private static void Operation()
{
    var tuple = (X: 10, Y: 20);
    var changeTuple = ChangeTuple(tuple);
}

private static ValueTuple<int, int> ChangeTuple(ValueTuple<int, int> tuple)
{
    tuple.Item1 = 100; // ex) tuple.X = 100;
    tuple.Item2 = 200; // ex) tuple.Y = 200;
    return tuple;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can simply replace `ValueTuple<int, int>` to `(int X, int Y)`:

```
private static (int X, int Y) ChangeTuple((int X, int Y) tuple)
{
    tuple.X = 100; 
    tuple.Y = 200; 
    return tuple;
}
```

For reference: [naming tuple's fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names)

---

Or you can use [deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct):

```
private static (int X, int Y) ChangeTuple(ValueTuple<int, int> tuple)
{
    var (X, Y) = tuple;
    X = 100;
    Y = 200;
    return (X, Y);
}
```

---

Please note that in both cases you are **not** modifying the original `ValueTuple` rather create a new one:

- In the first case it is because the `ValueTuple` is a `struct`, so it is passed by value
- In the second case we explicitly create a new named `ValueTuple`